# how to use substring in linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, c#-4.0

Hello I need a help in to use substring  in my liq code to get some lent of data which are saved in DB. i want to use in v.Description

v.Description.substring(0,399) something

there is my code

```
public static string BindeWorkOutDetails(int Id, Label Header, 
                     Label Title, Label Description)
        {
            DataClassesDataContext con = 
                  new DataClassesDataContext(con);
            var q = (from v in con.WorkoutSettings
                     where v.Id == Id
                     select new { v.Header ,v.Title, v.Description, 
                        v.ImageUrl }).First();
            Header.Text = q.Header;
            Title.Text = q.Title;            
            Description.Text = q.Description;
            return q.ImageUrl;
        }
```

please lest me know how can i use a substring in in Linq please re-code my this code

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Description` is a string you can do the following:

```
v.Description.Substring(0, 399);
```

Comment: You could also do it outside of the LINQ query when you assign the result to `Description.Text`:  `Description.Text = q.Description.Substring(0, 399);`

Comment: But only if `Description` will always be longer than or equal to 399 characters. If you attempt this with a string that is shorter than 399 characters, you will get an [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx#ddueExceptionsToggle). One solution to get around this: `v.Description.PadRight(399).Substring(0, 399).Trim()`